# How to customize the animation for the display of a popovercontroller?

Tags: ios5, core-animation, uipopovercontroller

I would like to customize the animation to display a uipopovercontroller so that it can slide in from right to left when it appears. I basically would like to simulate the menu you can see in Flipboard. Is there a way to customize the animation without having to write a popovercontroller? It seems that the default behavior has the slide in functionality but it is too fast to see it happening. I didn't find any property where i can set a transition style.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that isn't a popover that the Flipboard app is using.  It's most likely another UIView or UIViewController layered on top of the current view.  Much like the 'About' menu in Angry Birds.  Animating UIPopovers is also not going to be very easy, as they were never built for customization (or to be leak proof, or to even be very good in the first place).  My advice, create your [own](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover).  (I love github, so so much).